# Notepad++ overwrite text instead of adding?

Tags: notepad++

i pressed something, i dont know what but when i write stuff in notepad++ 
exemple:

and i want to add "whatever" between the "s" and "e" of "section", it will overwrite the whole line instead of just adding what im writing, please help me fix that :S

Comment: Did you press _insert_ key on your keyboard ?

Comment: oh my god i love you mate! xD

Answer (score 2):

tap "Ins" (insert) on your keyboard, that should make things better